# Как изменить отображение вложенности папок в VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Если в папке есть только одна вложенная папка, то VSCode автоматически сворачивает родительскую папку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чём, если в папку добавить любой другой файл, то ненавистного сжатия не произойдёт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли способ убрать функцию сжатия родительской папки, если  в ней находится только одна папка? Это очень мешает в работе, а постоянное добавление файла, пока не будет создана вторая вложенная папка грозит попасть в реп или на сервер, где она совершенно не нужна

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Settings** > вводим в строку поиска **Compact Folders** > **убираем галочку**.